# Mongo values not updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to simply increment a value of an object in mongoose and it seems to not want to go past 2?? Is there something I'm missing? I'm fairly new to Mongo

```
campsite.findOne({slug : req.body.campsite.slug }, function(err, site){

    if(!site.tracking){
        console.log("no previous tracking at all");
        site.tracking = {};
    }

    if(site.tracking[req.body.tracking_type] == undefined){
        console.log("no previous tracking of this type");
        site.tracking[req.body.tracking_type] = 1;
    }else{
        console.log("well count it then!");
        site.tracking[req.body.tracking_type] += + 1;
    }

    site.save(function (err, fluffy) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    res.send(200);
});
```

It just wont save the updated result? My Schema is below

```
var campsitesSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    address_line_1: String,
    address_line_2: String,
    county: String,
    postcode: String,
    loc: Array,
    website: String,
    email: String,
    telephone_1: String,
    telephone_2: String,
    description: String,
    slug:String,
    status:String,
    confirm_url_key: String,
    password: String,
    short_description: String,
    long_description: String,
    features: Array,
    tracking: {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're much better off using a update with a $inc modifier

```
campsite.update({slug : req.body.campsite.slug }, {$inc: { 'tracking[' + req.body.tracking_type + ']' : 1} });
```

Comment: You cant use 'tracking[' + req.body.tracking_type + ']'

Comment: @user3240114 Try 'tracking.' + req.body.tracking_type

Comment: @user3240114 what is the value of req.body.tracking_type ?

Comment: it's okay I've sorted it, seems the only way I could get round it was to replace the entire tracking object, see my answer

Comment: essentially i had to replace the whole object with the $set modifier, It also doesnt work if you dont have a callback